# Power BI Dax calculate the Sum% of Top 10 products

Tags: powerbi, dax

UserRequest

> I want to get the Sum of top 10 %,  ie. the third column which is % of
> Value / total value

---

### x

### Sample Data##

| ProductName | value | Ranking |  |
A1  | 10 | 1  | 10%

A2  | 8 | 2  | 8%

A3  | 6 | 3  | 6%
A4  | 4 | 4  | 4%
A5  | 2 | 5  | 2%
A6  | 1 | 6  | 1%
A7  | 1 | 7  | 1%
A8  | 1 | 8  | 1%
A9  | 1 | 9  | 1%
A10 | 1 | 10 | 1%
A11 | 1 | 11 | 1%
Total value = 100

Expected outcome The measure should return sum of Top 10% = 35%

**Here is the Dax I have built so far.**

```
Eq_TopN% = 
    VAR RANKMV = [RANKMV]
    VAR Top_N = 10
    //VAR RANKMV = RANKX(ALL(Eq_Bucket_tbl[Issuer]),Eq_Measures_tbl[MaxMV],,DESC,Dense)
    RETURN 

SUMX(TOPN(Top_N,CALCULATETABLE(ALLSELECTED(Eq_Bucket_tbl),FILTER(Eq_Master_Dates,Eq_Master_Dates[Date]=[MaxDateSelected])), [Total MV], ASC), [Total MV])


RANKMV = RANKX(
            ALL(Eq_Bucket_tbl[Issuer]),
            Eq_Measures_tbl[MaxMV]
            ,
            ,,Dense
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ranking column then just use calculate:

```
SumOfTOP = CALCULATE(sum(Sheet1[ % ]), Sheet1[ Ranking ] <= 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a measure to calculate the sum of percentages for the top 10 values.

```
    Sum of TOP10% =
    (
      CALCULATE (
          SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ),
          TOPN ( 10, 'Table' )
       ) / 100
     )
```

After creating the measure, go to measure tools by clicking on the measure, and then in the formatting section set the measure format to Percentage.
[image]

This should give you the desired result.

[image]